# spy service which itself has dependencies

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, ngxs

I can't seem to find an example for the following problem. I have a unit test for my NGXS state:

```
describe('Project store', () => {
    let store: Store;
    let projectService: ProjectService;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [NgxsModule.forRoot([ProjectState])]
        }).compileComponents();

        projectService = new ProjectService(); // error: needs httpClient

        store = TestBed.get(Store);
    }));

    it('should load projects', () => {

        const EXPECTED_PROJECTS = [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "description": "abc"
            },
            {
                "id": "1",
                "description": "abc"
            }
        ] as Project[];

        spyOn(projectService, 'loadProjects').and.returnValue(EXPECTED_PROJECTS);
        const expected: ProjectStateModel = {
            loadedProjects: EXPECTED_PROJECTS,
            createdProjects: []
        };
        store.dispatch(new LoadProjects());
        const actual = store.selectSnapshot(ProjectState.getState);
        expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    });

});
```

How do I spy on `ProjectService` when it itself needs the `httpClient`?

I have found examples on how do test a service which needs the `httpClient`, but now about how to mock a service that needs the client.

Now I know I could just write a mock service myself, but I am trying to find out if this can be done using jasmine spies.

Comment: You shouldn't ever be newing it up yourself, that's what the TestBed (and DI generally) is for. But basically you need to provide the dependencies of anything you're creating for real, in this case either using the HttpClientTestingModule or just creating your own "client" test double. But at that point, why *not* double the service instead?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah, I think that's what I'll do. I'll get the service via TestBed and then do spyOn on that. It's just a bit weird that I have to provide HttpClient even though I am not using it, but mocking the call to the service.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `HttpTestingController` in order to mock desired responses from your service, see the code below:

```
describe('Project store', () => {
  let store: Store;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        NgxsModule.forRoot([ProjectState])
      ],
      providers: [ProjectService]
    }).compileComponents();

    store = TestBed.get(Store);
  }));

  it('should load projects',
    inject([HttpTestingController], (controller: HttpTestingController) => {
      const EXPECTED_PROJECTS = [
        { 'id': '1', 'description': 'abc' },
        { 'id': '1', 'description': 'abc' }
      ] as Project[];
      const expected = {
        'projectsState': <ProjectStateModel>{
          loadedProjects: EXPECTED_PROJECTS,
          createdProjects: []
        }
      };
      store.dispatch(new LoadProjects());
      // expecting one GET request as a result of LoadProjects action
      const testReq = controller.expectOne(req => req.method === 'GET');
      // provide mock response
      testReq.flush(EXPECTED_PROJECTS);

      const actual = store.selectSnapshot(ProjectState.getState);
      expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    }));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, but would this not be more appropriate for testing the service itself? Because in my test scenario, I really don't care whether the correct request was executed, I want to mock the entire service method.